# Badge TextView Text is not aligned to center

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-7.0-nougat

Brand new to the android development...  I have a badge text over a button, but for some reason text is not aligned to center.

I have created a new fragment and set `Component Tree` to `relativeLayout`

Then I have added the button and the textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intercom_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_intercom_logo"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:shadowColor="@color/brownishGrey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intercom_badge_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/intercom_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/intercom_button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/intercom_button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
        android:elevation="11dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/intercom_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in `drawable/badge_circle` I have used.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thickness="8dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    >

    <solid
        android:color="#F00"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#F00" />

    <padding
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

This results in

[image]

From what I understand it is happening because textview properties set to

```
layout_width:wrap_content 
layout_height:wrap_content
```

But if I set them to static constraints like

```
layout_width:16dp
layout_height:16dp
```

Text still doesn't align. Also setting gravity or textalignment doesn't help

```
android:textAlignment="center"
android:gravity="center"
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: did you add a center tag on our android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Did I get this right? the problem is that the "10" isn't drawn in the middle of the red circle?

Comment: Is there a reason for not just adding the text to the button with `android:text="10"`. It should automatically center for you.

Comment: @DroiDev I dont't think so how do I do that? maybe I misunderstand you but isn't that a system library why do I need to edit that ?

Comment: @0X0nosugar yes, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

badge_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thickness="8dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    >

    <solid
        android:color="#F00"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#F00" />


</shape>
```

Change to the TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intercom_badge_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/intercom_button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/intercom_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/intercom_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
    android:elevation="11dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/intercom_button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="357dp" />
```

I removed the padding from inside of the badge circle and added in into the textview....seems to be fixed...